# In 'LIKE' operator needs to select 'NULL'(DB) values

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

This is a one typical Question asked my boss..

Q: how to select the value which are nulls in Database using LIKE operator..

I tried like below:

```
select c.ClaimID from claim c
where c.InjuredPartyFirstName like (''+coalesce(c.InjuredPartyFirstName,'')+'')
```

But this also not working........

Please help some one

Thanks in Advance...
vinay k

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not use

```
select c.ClaimID from claim c where c.InjuredPartyFirstName IS NULL
```

If this is some kind of strange test, try

```
select c.ClaimID from claim c 
where ISNULL(c.InjuredPartyFirstName, '') like ''
```

Comment: Using union of two selects for LIKE and NULL might improve query as well instead of using "ISNULL" - `select claimID from Claim where InjuiredPartyFirstName like '...' union select claimID from Claim where InjuiredPartyFirstName is null`

Comment: thank you for respond.... And this answer i gave but with COALESCE instead of ISNULL , he satisfied half....

Thanks
vinay

Answer (score 2):

Filtering by NULL values is performed like so:

```
select c.ClaimID 
from claim c 
where c.InjuredPartyFirstName IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

So the correct answer to your boss's trick question is that you can't do it directly with LIKE unless you want to slow the query down by coalescing the null values first. And then explain to him/her **why** a NULL is NULL and should not be capable of having a LIKE applied directly to it.

Edit: maybe this is just a test by your boss to filter the jedi's out from the pretenders?