# not able to retrieve if the table column has null value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have stored procedure to find customer, its working fine. If `Customer_City_Name` is null in the table then I am not able to retrieve the row. SP fails . how to do this 
I have to get result even if `Customer_City_Name` or `Customer_Country_Code` `IS NULL`

```
EXEC findCustomer null,'%',null,null,
```

SP code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE  findCustomer
  @customerNumber NVARCHAR(100),
  @customerNamePattern NVARCHAR(35),
  @customerCityNamePattern NVARCHAR(35),
  @customerCountryCode NVARCHAR(5)
AS

BEGIN
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(4000)
SET @SQL =
'
SELECT
c.Customer_Number,
c.Customer_Name,
c.Postal_Address_Identifier,
c.Customer_Street_Or_Road_Name,
c.Customer_City_Name,
c.Customer_Territory_Code,
c.Customer_Postal_Code,
c.Customer_Country_Code,
c.Telephone_Number,
c.Mobile_Telephone_Number,
c.Fax_Number,
c.Email_Address 
FROM Customer c  
WHERE c.Customer_Number LIKE ' +
        CASE WHEN @customerNumber IS NOT NULL
             THEN '''' + @customerNumber + ''''
             ELSE 'c.Customer_Number'
        END + '
AND c.Customer_Name LIKE ' +
        CASE WHEN @customerNamePattern IS NOT NULL
            THEN '''' + @customerNamePattern + ''''
            ELSE 'c.Customer_Name'
        END + '
AND c.Customer_City_Name LIKE ' +
        CASE WHEN @customerCityNamePattern IS NOT NULL
            THEN '''' +@customerCityNamePattern + ''''
            ELSE 'c.Customer_City_Name'
        END + '
AND c.Customer_Country_Code LIKE ' +
        CASE WHEN @customerCountryCode IS NOT NULL
            THEN '''' +@customerCountryCode + ''''
            ELSE 'c.Customer_Country_Code'
        END

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
```

Comment: GEEZ! Please **reformat** and clean up your post - this is a huge mess! ***Please*** highlight lines of code in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: You have a stored procedure that generates dynamic SQL and executes it. Couldn't you use parametrized queries instead? They'd be less vulnerable to injection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this issue by doing this

AND ISnull(c.Customer_City_Name,'''') LIKE ' +
                                                    CASE WHEN @customerCityNamePattern IS NOT NULL
                                                         THEN '''' +@customerCityNamePattern + ''''
                                                         ELSE 'isnull (c.Customer_City_Name,'''')'
                                                     END + '
                                                AND Isnull(c.Customer_Country_Code,'''') LIKE ' +
                                                    CASE WHEN @customerCountryCode IS NOT NULL
                                                         THEN '''' +@customerCountryCode + ''''
                                                         ELSE 'isnull(c.Customer_Country_Code , '''')'
                                                     END

1.Thanks to asafrob i have accepted your approach. 
2. Thanks to devio  [In 'LIKE' operator needs to select 'NULL'(DB) values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324368/in-like-operator-needs-to-select-nulldb-values)  I got idea from 
3.Thanks to jpmc26 -- > I like your answer .
Finally thanks to every one answered to my question

Comment: I didn't make this clear enough in my answer, but your dynamic SQL is very vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. Consider parametrized queries or at least some kind of input validation.

Comment: This is the only way .. I can produce the excepted result

Answer (score 0):

@user2218371 you should reconsider alternatives instead of dynamic SQL. anyway, this is an alternative code.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE  findCustomer
  @customerNumber NVARCHAR(100),
  @customerNamePattern NVARCHAR(35),
  @customerCityNamePattern NVARCHAR(35),
  @customerCountryCode NVARCHAR(5)
AS

BEGIN
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(4000)
SET @SQL =
'
SELECT
c.Customer_Number,
c.Customer_Name,
c.Postal_Address_Identifier,
c.Customer_Street_Or_Road_Name,
c.Customer_City_Name,
c.Customer_Territory_Code,
c.Customer_Postal_Code,
c.Customer_Country_Code,
c.Telephone_Number,
c.Mobile_Telephone_Number,
c.Fax_Number,
c.Email_Address 
FROM Customer c  
WHERE ' + 
    CASE WHEN  @customerNumber IS NOT NULL 
        THEN ' c.Customer_Number LIKE ''' + @customerNumber + '''' + 
            CASE WHEN  @customerNamePattern IS NOT NULL THEN ' AND ' ELSE '' END
        ELSE '' 
    END  +
    CASE WHEN   @customerNamePattern IS NOT NULL 
        THEN ' c.Customer_Name LIKE ''' +  @customerNamePattern + '''' + 
            CASE WHEN  @customerCityNamePattern IS NOT NULL THEN ' AND ' ELSE '' END
        ELSE '' 
    END  + 
    CASE WHEN   @customerCityNamePattern IS NOT NULL 
        THEN ' c.Customer_City_Name LIKE ''' +  @customerCityNamePattern + '''' + 
            CASE WHEN  +@customerCountryCode IS NOT NULL THEN ' AND ' ELSE '' END
        ELSE '' 
    END  + 
    CASE WHEN    @customerCountryCode IS NOT NULL 
        THEN ' c.Customer_Country_Code LIKE ''' +  @customerCountryCode + ''''
        ELSE '' 
    END     

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
```

Answer (score 0):

When one of the fields is `NULL`, your `WHERE` clause looks like this:

```
WHERE c.Customer_Number LIKE c.Customer_Number
```

This is clearly intentional, since it is part of the `CASE` statements.

However, `LIKE` doesn't return true for a pair of `NULL` values. (`NULL` is not `LIKE` `NULL`.) This is pretty typical behavior for `NULL`. `=` does the same thing.

See this very simple SQL Fiddle for a demonstration: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/82a23/3/0.

Assuming I'm reading this correctly, you want to simply ignore the column's value when the procedure argument is `NULL`. In that case, you will need to adjust your query to leave out the clause entirely or put some always true expression in its place when the argument is `NULL`.

If you insist on sticking with your dynamic SQL building function (which you should not), try this for your `CASE` statements:

```
WHERE ' +
CASE WHEN @customerNumber IS NOT NULL
     THEN 'c.Customer_Number LIKE ''' + @customerNumber + ''''
     ELSE '0=0'
END + '
```

Answer (score 0):

`Null` values cant be compared with any other value, that means you don't get a `True` or a `False`.
To work around this issue I use the `ISNULL` built in function that checks if the value is null, and if it is returns your default value.

You should apply this function to each column where a `null` value is an option.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx

Answer (score 0):

brother, so your query mainly is to perform select function to search for existing customer info

try to modify your where condition as sample below

```
Select ....
From .....
WHERE (@Customer_Number is null or c.Customer_Number like @Customer_Number + '%')
AND (@customerNamePattern is null or c.Customer_Name  like @customerNamePattern + '%' )
AND (@customerCityNamePatternis null or c.Customer_City_Name   like @customerCityNamePattern+ '%' )
AND (@customerCountryCode is null or c.c.Customer_Country_Code like @customerCountryCode + '%' )
```

Comment: Thanks for the info  
It’s a customer search , I have added a pagination to this code , so I have added to dynamic SQL. Easiest way of fixing is update table all four column as not null ?

Comment: sorry? so your question right now is update your table with not null columns value? this is blur, can u update your question? ^___^